# Simple DOM Parser PHP expecting exactly one result from CSS selector

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

Hey I have a problem with Simple DOM parser which is driving me nuts.

This works OK:

```
foreach($html->find('input[name=sex]') as $e)
echo $e->value;
```

Even if its only 1 result.

However this doesn't work:

```
echo $html->find('input[name=sex]')->value;
```

I don't want really use foreach because I expect only 1 result.
So someone could help me with second block of code?

Cheers

Comment: `->find()` returns a results object, which can be boiled to an array of matching elements. You're doing `->value` on the whole array, instead of one of the actual elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm), the second parameter is the index you wish to find.  Set that to 0 to return the first (*0th*) element rather than an array of objects:

> Find elements by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise return an array of object.

```
$html->find('input[name=sex]', 0)->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html->find('input[name=sex]')[0]->value;
```

It seems `find` returns an array so using index would help you.

Use the code above.

Comment: This kind of array dereferencing is not available before PHP 5.4

Comment: Then he can do the logic and use the property after assigning it to the variable first.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use for-each on something, it is an array/collection, even if there is one element. You are asking to echo an entire array, for which which may need `print_r`. As another poster suggested, use a subscript.